# Blocking access to a specific url

Tags: linux, iptables, blocking, traffic, internet-filter

I have a lightweight linux device which I would like to block from accessing one specific URL. Instead of making the request to the external URL, I would like to return the contents of a local file.

The most common solutions for accomplishing this seem to be:

- Using squid (not suitable because the required resources are not available)
- DNS blocking using /etc/hosts (not suitable because I only want to block a specific url, not an entire domain)

I am unsure whether this can be done solely using iptables? Are there any other simple solutions?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use iptables:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m string --string "superuser.com" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

You may also be interested in [DansGuardian](http://dansguardian.org/).